# JSON.parse javascript string

Tags: javascript, json

In javascript, I need to parse a string into what would be the equivalent of a javascript array such as:

```
[["2016-12-21",101.58],["2016-12-22",209.56]]
```

The data I have, along with my attempt at parsing it and the error message looks like this:

```
str = "[[&#34;2016-11-17&#34;,771.22998],[&#34;2016-11-16&#34;,764.47998],[&#34;2016-11-15&#34;,758.48999],[&#34;2016-11-14&#34;,736.080017],[&#34;2016-11-11&#34;,754.02002],[&#34;2016-11-10&#34;,762.559998],[&#34;2016-11-09&#34;,785.309998],[&#34;2016-11-08&#34;,790.51001],[&#34;2016-11-07&#34;,782.52002],[&#34;2016-11-04&#34;,762.02002],[&#34;2016-11-03&#34;,762.130005],[&#34;2016-11-02&#34;,768.700012],[&#34;2016-11-01&#34;,783.609985],[&#34;2016-10-31&#34;,784.539978]]"

JSON.parse(str)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2(…)
```

I attempted to remove some of the special characters from the string (&, #, ;, etc.), which slightly changed the error message, but I was never able to get to my end result. I figured I would put it in stackoverflow starting from the beginning, because there is most likely a better start-to-finish solution than what I was attempting.

Comment: ur data in str has the double quotes as html entities (`&#34;` vs `"`), and that is not valid json. The array at the top of your question has the quotes correct, so some other process is mucking up your string

Comment: `str` is not valid json when it uses html entities as quotes. Fix the source. Use jsonlint.com to validate your json

Comment: Are you getting this data from browser View source window?

Comment: How are you getting the data into the string in the first place? It's usually not a good idea to put JSON data into a string literal programmatically.

Comment: See comment below (data comes from python, specifically a csv file read with pandas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naively,

```
JSON.parse(str.replace(/&#34;/g,'"'));
```

will work, but you should figure out why your double quotes are getting turned into HTML entities.

Comment: This worked. My data originates from using Python on the server side, and using the pandas library. The call looks like this:                                         `str = stock_data.to_json(orient='values') `

Where `stock_data` was read in from csv using read_csv.

Comment: I don't know python, but a method called `to_json` seems like its not working properly if it does not return valid `JSON`

Comment: I am using Flask (which uses Jinja). I think the json properties get lost when I send the JSON object (from python) to the html template, which has inline javascript. (I called it like `'{{ str }}'`)

Answer (score 0):

### Description

This will allow for the numerical ascii character of any character.  However, if you only have quotations to remove it isn't too much to run a replace.

```js
var str = "[[&#34;2016-11-17&#34;,771.22998],[&#34;2016-11-16&#34;,764.47998],[&#34;2016-11-15&#34;,758.48999],[&#34;2016-11-14&#34;,736.080017],[&#34;2016-11-11&#34;,754.02002],[&#34;2016-11-10&#34;,762.559998],[&#34;2016-11-09&#34;,785.309998],[&#34;2016-11-08&#34;,790.51001],[&#34;2016-11-07&#34;,782.52002],[&#34;2016-11-04&#34;,762.02002],[&#34;2016-11-03&#34;,762.130005],[&#34;2016-11-02&#34;,768.700012],[&#34;2016-11-01&#34;,783.609985],[&#34;2016-10-31&#34;,784.539978]]";
// regex to get the ascii number
var r = /\&#(\d\d);/gi;
// replaces each numerical ascii character with their character representation
str = str.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp)); } );

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode your encoded string reusing the HTML parser in something more portable, a lot faster, reusable. regex patterns are specific to the current problem and each time you encounter e different character you'll have write and rewrite a new pattern. I use an encapsulated function method similar to this:

```
function htmlParse( x ) {
     var c = document.createElement("div");
         c.innerHTML = x;
  return c.innerText;       
 };
```

Now let's decode your retrieved string...

```
var str = "[[&#34;2016-11-17&#34;,771.22998],[&#34;2016-11-16&#34;,764.47998],[&#34;2016-11-15&#34;,758.48999],[&#34;2016-11-14&#34;,736.080017],[&#34;2016-11-11&#34;,754.02002],[&#34;2016-11-10&#34;,762.559998],[&#34;2016-11-09&#34;,785.309998],[&#34;2016-11-08&#34;,790.51001],[&#34;2016-11-07&#34;,782.52002],[&#34;2016-11-04&#34;,762.02002],[&#34;2016-11-03&#34;,762.130005],[&#34;2016-11-02&#34;,768.700012],[&#34;2016-11-01&#34;,783.609985],[&#34;2016-10-31&#34;,784.539978]]";
```

|>>

```
var decoded = htmlParse( str );
console.log( decoded );
```

and see if parsing with json succeeds

```
var arr = JSON.parse( decoded );
console.log( arr );
```

and here is the snippet...

```js
    var str = "[[&#34;2016-11-17&#34;,771.22998],[&#34;2016-11-16&#34;,764.47998],[&#34;2016-11-15&#34;,758.48999],[&#34;2016-11-14&#34;,736.080017],[&#34;2016-11-11&#34;,754.02002],[&#34;2016-11-10&#34;,762.559998],[&#34;2016-11-09&#34;,785.309998],[&#34;2016-11-08&#34;,790.51001],[&#34;2016-11-07&#34;,782.52002],[&#34;2016-11-04&#34;,762.02002],[&#34;2016-11-03&#34;,762.130005],[&#34;2016-11-02&#34;,768.700012],[&#34;2016-11-01&#34;,783.609985],[&#34;2016-10-31&#34;,784.539978]]";


    var decoded = htmlParse(str);
    console.log(decoded);

    var arr = JSON.parse(decoded);
    console.log(arr);

    function htmlParse(x) {
      var c = document.createElement("div");
      c.innerHTML = x;
      return c.innerText;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the `json` package to write the data, set the `ensure_ascii` argument to false.

```
with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

For Python2.x, use the `codecs` library to set the encoding of your output file when you open it.